# Frontpage with images

Tags: media

I want to make a frontage with the Views module. On the frontpage, you can see 3 images, horizontal aligned. I don't understand the Views module very well, but I thought you can make for example a page with the Views module where you can add content that already exists on other pages. 
So I don't know what to do now, as my images don't exist anywhere.

Comment: "my images don't exist anywhere" - what do you mean by that? How can a visitor see 3 images on the frontpage if these don't even exist? :D

Answer (score 1):

You're saying you want images from another site? I've got two pretty basic suggestions...

1. build them into your theme. You'll want to create a div (or three) in a template for the front page, adn then you can add them in with css pretty easily.
2. display them with a block. Create a new block, make sure you turn on HTML for your input and then add your images:

Enable the block for the region you want, and tell the block to only display on the front page. You'll want to do some simple css theming to that block, as well, to make them look how you want.

Both these options are just to display images. What do you want to do after that? Will clicking them take the user to another page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create a frontpage with views if you only want to display what's in the view

*create a new view
*add a page display
*add your fields and set your display setting (html list, table, etc...)
*set a path for your page display (example 'pictures')
*save your view

once you have your view saved, go to this page admin/config/system/site-information
and go to the frontpage settings. replace 'node' with your views page path (in this case replace 'node' with 'pictures')

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information but I have to add fields to my view from other content types but my 3 images are not on the website. there is no place where my images already are.